# How do I activate this HTML class in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I have a web tool plugin in Wordpress which I need to active a class that disables my selection.
Here is the link:
https://sotogloves.com/product/customization-tool/?GD_NONCE=24e370d2e1

This is the line that disables my functionality:

```
class="mspc-menu-item disabled"
```

How do I delete the "disabled" portion to have my functionalities active?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to do something like this in your js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mspc-accordion a').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('disabled');
    });
});
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/z8aurqc1/3/